# Как посмотреть из-за чего падает docker контейнер

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Собираю стек lamp + nginx для отдачи статики,
получился вот такой docker-compose.yml

```
  version: "3"

  services:

      nginx:
          image: nginx
          volumes:
               - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
               - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
               - ./data/:/data/
          ports:
              - "80:80"
              - "443:443"
          networks:
              - front
              - backend


      apache:
          build: ./docker/apache
          container_name: app41-apache 
          volumes:
              - ./:/var/www/
              - ./docker/apache/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

              - ./data/:/data/

          networks:
              - backend
          # command: "tail -f /dev/null"



      db:
          image: "mysql:5.6" 
          container_name: app40-mysql            
          volumes:
              # - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
              - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql            
          environment:
                 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
                 MYSQL_DATABASE: app
                 MYSQL_USER: root
                 MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
          networks:
              - backend
          ports:
              - 3306:3306 


  networks:
      front:
          external:
              name: front
      backend:
```

Как видно, apache я собираю из ./docker/apache

```
FROM php:5-apache

# PHP extensions
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 



 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli 

#    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
#    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
#    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf
RUN mkdir -p /data/wwwlog/soft.ru/
RUN mkdir -p /data/www/soft.ru/

RUN echo '<VirtualHost *:80> \n\
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost \n\
        ServerName soft4me.ru \n\
        ServerAlias soft4me.ru \n\
        ErrorLog /data/wwwlog/soft.ru/error.log \n\
        CustomLog /data/wwwlog/soft.ru/access.log combined \n\
        DocumentRoot /data/www/soft.ru/ \n\
</VirtualHost>   ' > /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf






# Apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Но при запуске docker-compose up -d --build у меня падает контейнер apache

Погуглив, везде пишут, что нужно посмотреть логи, docker logs ID,  но, по docker ps его просто нет. Другой вариант, запустить docker run -it ИМЯ bash, но у меня нет имени контейнера, и может ошибка в docker-compose.yml  а не в Dockerfile

Comment: Думается мне, что проблема в dockerfile, а именно отсутствует команда, которую контейнер выполняет по умолчанию `CMD`

Answer (score 1):

Используя [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) вы может обращаться по имени сервиса, указанного в  файле `docker-compose.yml`, например:

```
docker-compose run apache
docker-compose run --rm apache
docker-compose logs apache

# и также процессы
docker-compose ps
```

Если сервис не зависит от других то будет запущен в одиночестве, если указаны depends_on, то сначала стартуют зависимости затем контейнер

**Еще проще**, запустите сервисы в обычном режиме: `docker-compose up`, **без** опции `-d, --detach` и логи будут выводится в терминале.

**Также**, можно указать имя контейнера через `container_name` в `docker-compose.yml`:

```
container_name: my-super-container
```

и конечно, **не забываем**:

```
docker-compose --help
docker-compose help <COMMAND>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile хочет ENTRYPOINT

Без него оно не любит работать автоматом.

Ну, типа, оно собирается, отрабатывает, но без ENTRYPOINT закрывается, т.к. нет инструкции для продолжения работы.

Попробуй копать в эту сторону.